Oracle multiple order by query optimization
My Table structure & data-
CREATE TABLE BRAND_OFFERS
(
    ID NUMBER(15,0)
    , NAME VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)
    , OPEN DATE
    , CLOSE DATE
    , ENROLLED DATE
);


-- expired offers
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(1,  'Holiday1',  date'2024-03-20', date'2024-03-30', date'2024-03-22');
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(2,  'Holiday2',  date'2024-03-20', date'2024-03-25', null);
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(3,  'Holiday3',  date'2024-04-25', date'2024-04-30', date'2024-04-27');
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(4,  'Holiday4',  date'2024-05-21', date'2024-05-26', date'2024-05-23');
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(5,  'Holiday5',  date'2024-05-22', date'2024-05-25', null);

-- active offers
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(6,  'Holiday6',  date'2024-05-15', date'2024-06-10', date'2024-05-26');
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(7,  'Holiday7',  date'2024-05-20', date'2024-06-10', date'2024-05-21');
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(8,  'Holiday8',  date'2024-05-20', date'2024-06-10', null);
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(9,  'Holiday9',  date'2024-05-20', date'2024-06-10', null);
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(10, 'Holiday10', date'2024-05-20', date'2024-06-10', date'2024-05-22');

-- future offers
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(11, 'Holiday11', date'2024-05-30', date'2024-06-05', null);
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(12, 'Holiday12', date'2024-06-01', date'2024-06-05', null);
insert into BRAND_OFFERS values(13, 'Holiday13', date'2024-06-01', date'2024-06-08', null);

Requirement- Basically, the Festival Offers are divided into below categories:

Offer Expired - Offer Close date < sysdate
Offer Active and Enrolled - sysdate is between Close & Open date, inclusive. Already Enrolled.
Offer Active - sysdate is between Close & Open date, inclusive. But no Enrollment.
Offer Future - Offer Open date > sysdate

I need to display the values from BRAND_OFFERS table, Ordered By as per above categories. First Expired, then Active, then Future offers.
Oracle Query to achieve this-
with initial_op as (
    select id, name,
        OPEN as open_date,
        CLOSE as closure_date,
        ENROLLED as enroll_date,
        case 
            when CLOSE < sysdate
                then 'Offer Expired'
            when OPEN > sysdate
                then 'Offer Future'
            when ENROLLED is not null
                then 'Offer Active and Enrolled'
            else 'Offer Active but yet to Enroll'
        end offer_status,
        
        case 
            when CLOSE < sysdate
                then 1
            when ENROLLED is not null
                then 2
            else 3
        end seq
    from BRAND_OFFERS ),
    
x as (select * from initial_op where seq = 1
        order by closure_date ),
y as (select * from initial_op where seq = 2
        order by enroll_date ),
z as (select * from initial_op where seq = 3
        order by open_date)

select * from x
    union all
select * from y    
    union all
select * from z;

This query gives me the desired output. The same query, instead of multiple with & union all, I tried with order by (multiple) case when... but not getting the correct order.
--not working
order by 
    case when CLOSE < sysdate then CLOSE
         when ENROLLED is not null then ENROLLED
         else OPEN
    end

Can the working query be optimized further?
fiddle

What is your question? You end asking about optimization but the rest of your post says nothing about performance.

I'm able to achieve the required Output using the query that I have posted. But since it involves multiple order by & Unions, I strongly felt there must be a better alternative. And I didn't have any alternate query or large amount of data to compare my performance against. But I got my answer. Thanks.

As this currently stands, you're likely to end up with three passes through the table, ie
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |              |    13 |  2886 |    12  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL           |              |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW               |              |     5 |  1110 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    SORT ORDER BY     |              |     5 |  1010 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| BRAND_OFFERS |     5 |  1010 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   VIEW               |              |     3 |   666 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    SORT ORDER BY     |              |     3 |   606 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| BRAND_OFFERS |     3 |   606 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |   VIEW               |              |     5 |  1110 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    SORT ORDER BY     |              |     5 |  1010 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| BRAND_OFFERS |     5 |  1010 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Whether not that is a good or bad thing depends highly on those predicates in the CASE (ie, you could fold them into the query if there were appropriate indexes etc).  Assuming that is not the case, you can change your ORDER BY to drop this back to one pass on the table
SQL> with initial_op as (
  2      select id, name,
  3          OPEN as open_date,
  4          CLOSE as closure_date,
  5          ENROLLED as enroll_date,
  6          case
  7              when CLOSE < sysdate
  8                  then 'Offer Expired'
  9              when OPEN > sysdate
 10                  then 'Offer Future'
 11              when ENROLLED is not null
 12                  then 'Offer Active and Enrolled'
 13              else 'Offer Active but yet to Enroll'
 14          end offer_status,
 15          case
 16              when CLOSE < sysdate
 17                  then 1
 18              when ENROLLED is not null
 19                  then 2
 20              else 3
 21          end seq
 22      from BRAND_OFFERS )
 23  select *
 24  from initial_op
 25  order by seq,
 26    case
 27      when seq = 1 then closure_date
 28      when seq = 2 then enroll_date
 29      when seq = 2 then open_date
 30    end;

  ID NAME                 OPEN_DATE CLOSURE_D ENROLL_DA OFFER_STATUS                          SEQ
---- -------------------- --------- --------- --------- ------------------------------ ----------
   2 Holiday2             20-MAR-24 25-MAR-24           Offer Expired                           1
   1 Holiday1             20-MAR-24 30-MAR-24 22-MAR-24 Offer Expired                           1
   3 Holiday3             25-APR-24 30-APR-24 27-APR-24 Offer Expired                           1
   5 Holiday5             22-MAY-24 25-MAY-24           Offer Expired                           1
   4 Holiday4             21-MAY-24 26-MAY-24 23-MAY-24 Offer Expired                           1
   7 Holiday7             20-MAY-24 10-JUN-24 21-MAY-24 Offer Active and Enrolled               2
  10 Holiday10            20-MAY-24 10-JUN-24 22-MAY-24 Offer Active and Enrolled               2
   6 Holiday6             15-MAY-24 10-JUN-24 26-MAY-24 Offer Active and Enrolled               2
  13 Holiday13            01-JUN-24 08-JUN-24           Offer Future                            3
   8 Holiday8             20-MAY-24 10-JUN-24           Offer Active but yet to Enroll          3
   9 Holiday9             20-MAY-24 10-JUN-24           Offer Active but yet to Enroll          3
  11 Holiday11            30-MAY-24 05-JUN-24           Offer Future                            3
  12 Holiday12            01-JUN-24 05-JUN-24           Offer Future                            3


Thanks a lot Connor. This solution works perfectly for me. Just a small typo in your answer, for SQL->line 29      when seq = 3 then open_date. If we correct that, then Output is as expected.

You can define your categories in a cte making IDs in order you want. Then join categories cte to your table and order by category ID. This cte gives you option to rearrange and/or rename categories just if you do change IDs you should adjust Inner Join's ON clause accordingly...
With
    categories (ID, CATEGORY)  AS
        ( Select 1, 'Expired' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'Active and Enrolled' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'Active' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Future' From Dual 
        )

--      S Q L :
Select      o.ID, o.NAME, o.OPEN as OPEN_DATE, o.CLOSE as CLOSURE_DATE, o.ENROLLED as ENROLL_DATE, 
            c.CATEGORY
From        BRAND_OFFERS o
Inner Join  categories c ON(c.ID = Case When SYSDATE > o.CLOSE Then 1
                                        When SYSDATE Between o.OPEN And o.CLOSE And ENROLLED Is Not Null Then 2
                                        When SYSDATE Between o.OPEN And o.CLOSE And ENROLLED Is Null Then 3
                                        When SYSDATE < o.OPEN Then 4
                                   End
                           )
Order By  c.ID, 
          Case c.ID When 1 Then o.CLOSE
                    When 2 Then o.ENROLLED
          Else o.OPEN
          End

/*        R e s u l t :
  ID NAME            OPEN_DATE CLOSURE_DATE ENROLL_DATE CATEGORY           
---- --------------- --------- ------------ ----------- -------------------
   2 Holiday2        20.03.24  25.03.24                 Expired            
   1 Holiday1        20.03.24  30.03.24     22.03.24    Expired            
   3 Holiday3        25.04.24  30.04.24     27.04.24    Expired            
   5 Holiday5        22.05.24  25.05.24                 Expired            
   4 Holiday4        21.05.24  26.05.24     23.05.24    Expired            
   7 Holiday7        20.05.24  10.06.24     21.05.24    Active and Enrolled
  10 Holiday10       20.05.24  10.06.24     22.05.24    Active and Enrolled
   6 Holiday6        15.05.24  10.06.24     26.05.24    Active and Enrolled
   8 Holiday8        20.05.24  10.06.24                 Active             
   9 Holiday9        20.05.24  10.06.24                 Active             
  11 Holiday11       30.05.24  05.06.24                 Future             
  13 Holiday13       01.06.24  08.06.24                 Future             
  12 Holiday12       01.06.24  05.06.24                 Future              */


This optimizes first part of my query. First Expired, then Active, then Future offers are grouped nicely. But sorting within each group is not taken care of.
Within 'Expired' offers, sorting by 'o.CLOSE'. Within 'Active & Enrolled' offers, sorting by 'o.ENROLLED '.  For other 2, sorting by 'o.OPEN'.

@satyaprakashPanigrahi Just updated the answer.

Now this works :). Damn, if only there was an option to accept multiple answers :)).
Thanks a lot dr.
